# PCA анализ и визуализация

Tags: python

у меня имеется набор неразмеченных данных данного вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу провезти анализ PCA и с этим набором и визуализировать его.
Я просто не до конца понимаю, что делать с этим набором, так как обычно они содержат больше информации.

Comment: Вы уверены, что именно `PCA` вам нужно? И что вы вообще планируете дальше делать с этими данными? Если кластеризовать, то `PCA` может помочь. А если просто диаграмму рассеяния, например, хотите нарисовать, то берите `t-SNE`.

Comment: А так то я бы сначала лучше распределение каждой колонки глянул, ну и карту корреляции колонок бы построил. Хотя зачем это всё всё-равно непонятно пока.

Answer (score 0):

Если под словом "как" вы подразумеваете "какими средствами" -  то ответ: модуль sklearn.decomposition метод PCA.

Если вы спрашиваете как визуализировать -  то тут вариантов много, например с помощью plotly https://plotly.com/python/pca-visualization/  или вот так https://machinelearningmastery.com/principal-component-analysis-for-visualization/

Что значит *"обычно (??) они содержат больше информации"* -  совершенно непонятно. Больше параметров? Больше объектов? И как это влияет на метод, который вы будете использовать?